# Need to perform some not so straight forward data processing in Access 2010

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table in Access that is setup like the one in the photo. What I need to do is this:

For each part no, I want to sum the total Qty for each month and type (Ordered and Demand). Then I need to cap the qty in the rows where the type is = to Orders to the value of the Qty where the type is = to Orders, when the sum of the Qty for Ordered is greater than Demand. Let me try to explain it another way.

I want to look at a subset of the master data, in this case the subset is by part no (rows with identical part numbers). For this subset I want to have two sets of sums. 1. The sum of qty with type = Ordered AND  2. a sum of qty with type = Demand. If the sum for Ordered is greater than demand, I want to change the Qty for Ordered to be the value of the Qty for Demand.

Essentially, the business reason is that for reporting purposes the total Qty for Ordered shouldn't be more than Demand in a given month, for a part number.

Looking at the photo, the rows in red will need to change because the sum of the qty is 30, which is greater than the sum of qty for the green rows (25). The red rows qty should be changed to 20 and 5 to match the green rows.

Whew, hope this made sense because it is hard to explain. I have tried many things for a couple weeks now, and I am a bit fuzzy on the details so I will just give a high level. Ok so what have I tried:

1. I have tried to join the table to iself, using part no (and date I believe) to join on, but that doesn't work because the sum would somehow be incorrect sometimes.
2. Pivot the table, using the transform and pivot functions in Access but it's important for me to keep the individual dates in tact and when I pivoted it I had to roll it up on a month basis. This gives me the row structure I need to make the changes but I don't know how to get back the original date format after I am done.

I am guessing I need some VBA code that loops through each part no, but I am not big on VBA code and I don't have much time to learn it. Any suggestions? I know this is long winded but its a complicated problem (at least for me). Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: @MatthewD, the problem I have with such a query is that I have to do it for each set of unique part numbers at a time and not the entire data set. So, I don't know how to write sql to operate in subgroups of data.

Comment: I imagined your report as one row with part number, month, total DEMAND, and total ORDERED, for each combination of part number and month.  Re-reading the question today has me suspecting that's not what you really want.  If you want your report to include all the detail rows, but with ORDERED values adjusted as you described, I don't think it's practical (maybe not even possible) with only Access SQL.  I think you would need to do it with VBA or some other coding language.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I realized after spending so much time on it. I am not really sharp on VBA though.